# How to get MS SQL Stored Procedure return value In PHP with PDO?

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures, pdo

Simple example

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertLoginInPHP]
    @login as nvarchar(50), @password as nvarchar(50), @resultOK as int, @resultnot as int

AS
BEGIN
    SET @resultOK = 10
    SET @resultnot = 1

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Login = @login)
        BEGIN
            SELECT @resultnot as return // 1
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO Users (Login,Password) VALUES(@login,@password)
            SELECT @resultOK as return // 10
        END
END
```

**and In php**

```
$query = ("EXECUTE InsertLogin :login, :password");
$query_stored = $conn->prepare($query);
$query_stored->bindvalue(':login', $login);
$query_stored->bindvalue(':password', $password);   
$query_stored->execute();
```

**How can I get return value ( @resultnot or @resultOK ) in php?** 
**And How can I get and use return value in JSON?**
Like this

```
json_encode(array('status'=>'Ok','return'=>$query_sotored[resultOK])));
```

Comment: you need to use `fetchAll` on `$query_stored`: `$query_stored->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

Comment: Thanks Ali.
How do i get return value (@resultnot or @resultOK) after `fetchAll` `$query_stored->execute();`  
Like this: 
`$queryAfterExec = $query_stored->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` 
`$queryAfterExec[@resultOK] ` or difirent way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fetch a row from the statement, then access the column from the array this returns.

```
$query = ("EXECUTE InsertLogin :login, :password");
$query_stored = $conn->prepare($query);
$query_stored->bindvalue(':login', $login);
$query_stored->bindvalue(':password', $password);   
$query_stored->execute();
$row = $query_stored->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode(array('status'=>'Ok','return'=>$row['return'])))
```